Where can I find good and cheap historical options data API?
I'm looking for an API that can provide historical option contract prices (OCHLV) for USA stocks and preferably a list of option symbols so I don't have to generate them manually.
I tried working with polygon but they don't have data for days in which they don't have trades and their volume seems to be 0 or much lower than any number that makes sense.
For example in 2022 an ATM AAPL expiring in 3 months had 0 volume on some trading days in polygon (hence no data) , while nowadays the volume is ~28000.
WB

I don't know of any free data sources, but OptionMetrics is usually preferred by academics.

I think databento could maybe be a good choice

This question is similar to: What data sources are available online?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
